# Polymorphism for Batch Processing in Salesforce

Tags: apex, batch, polymorphism

Edit: Have edited the title in the hopes that anyone in the future looking for help on a related topic can find this easily. Here is a great way to implement polymophism with batch classes: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/156010/40851

I'm writing a few job classes: Job1, Job2, and so on.

```
global class Job1 implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

    private String query;

    global Job1(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    global void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    global String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope){
        // process each batch of records

    }    

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        // other logic goes here
    }    

}
```

I've created 5 such classes like this.

Next, I want to be able to use polymorphism and instantiate job objects as such:

```
Database.Batchable<sObject> j1 = new Job1();
```

Now, I'll do `j1.setQuery('SELECT Name from Account');`

However, doing this results in:

```
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Database.Batchable<SObject>].setQuery(String)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Job1 j1 = new Job1();` instead of `Database.Batchable<sObject> j1 = new Job1();`? I feel like if the `setQuery` method is only defined on the Job1 class, you'd have to be calling the method on an instance of a Job1

Comment: My end goal is to create something of an object factory, which is why I require the polymorphism.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To consolidate your code, set up an abstract class:

```
public abstract class BaseJob implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
    String query;
    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    public abstract void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, SObject[] scope);
    public abstract void finish(Database.BatchableContext context);
}
```

Now, we can implement your JobX classes:

```
public class Job1 extends BaseJob {
    public override void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, SObject[] scope) {
        // Do whatever we need to do
    }
    public override void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        // And finish up
    }
}
```

Finally, we just need to call your job:

```
BaseJob j = new Job1();
j.setQuery('select id from lead');
Database.executeBatch(j);
```

Or dynamically:

```
public static void doJob(Type className, String withQuery) {
    BaseJob j = (BaseJob)className.newInstance();
    j.setQuery(withQuery);
    Database.executeBatch(j);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. Am still learning the ropes at Salesforce, apologies if it was a silly question.

Comment: @Shiva I'm glad I could help. It's definitely a useful pattern to know about, it can consolidate a lot of code.

Answer (score 3):

There is an Object Oriented Programming concept.

> If user has defined a constructor in a class. The default constructor
>   doesn't work or can be called. If user defined constructor signature is same as default constructor. User defined constructor will override the default constructor.

So, you have defined a constructor:-

```
global Job1(String query) 
{
        this.query = query;
}
```

It takes argument type `String`. Because of this no argument constructor (default constructor) is removed from class definition.

If you want to use `new Job()`, define the constructor as below but make sure `query` need to be set:

```
global Job1() 
{
     // TO DO
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, note that inheritance isn't always the best approach. Where you have common behaviour (methods), classes that support those methods can be identified via an interface:

```
global interface QueryConfigurable { 
    void setQuery(String query;
}
```

like this:

```
global class Job1 implements QueryConfigurable, ... {
    ...
}
```

Would result in a cast for this example, but in other cases could be a bit cleaner:

```
Job1 j = new Job1();
((QueryConfigurable) j).setQuery('select id from lead');
Database.executeBatch(j);
```

With this approach you can compose functionality using multiple small interfaces; inheritance is an all or nothing approach.