# can we override start() method for batch apex

Tags: apex, batch, polymorphism

can we override start() method of the Batchable interface? If no please specify why?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? What are you trying to do?

Comment: In an interview it is asked that can we override start() method of batch interface. I don't know the answer of this. although I know we can override execute() and finish() method by your ans on this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/156008/polymorphism-for-batch-processing-in-salesforce/156010#156010 
but here you also did not override start() method @sfdcfox

Comment: My apologies, that answer isn't correct. You (and Nagendra) have conflated implementation with overriding.

Comment: then what is the correct answer will you please explain ? @sfdcfox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing a `Batchable` interface, you have three methods which you must `implement`.

```
void execute(Database.BatchableContext param1, List<Object> param2);

void finish(Database.BatchableContext param1);

Iterable/QueryLocator  start(Database.BatchableContext param1);
```

So **No**, you cannot override `start` method of a batch class, you can only `implement` it.

Comment: Note that when you are "overriding" a method, you are using the `override` keyword.

Comment: thanks for your reply

Comment: Yes `override` is a wrong word to use, it should be `implement`

Comment: This is only a partial answer since you can write a `virtual` implementation of `Batchable` and make the `start` implementation `virtual`. You can then create a subclass from there and `override` that `virtual` `start` method.

Comment: Additionally, you should say "**must** implement" instead of "can implement" (obviously you can delay that to an extent by marking the class `abstract` and adding an `abstract` implementation of one or more of the interface methods).

Answer (score 3):

When you implement an interface, you aren't overriding anything. You're simply stating that the class will have these particular methods available. This is why the keyword for using an interface is `implements`. Aside from that, `virtual` and `abstract` methods can be overridden using the `overrides` keyword. Note that this requires that the class in question has a parent class. I see you noted in the comments something about a parent Job class; this was meant to demonstrate how to reduce the number of times you need to fully implement the start method. You could make it `virtual`, which would allow it to be overridden in child classes that use it.

The main summary is that one shouldn't conflate `override` (used by `virtual` and `abstract` methods), and `implements`, which deals with ensuring a class has the provided methods to be run through the interface (the compiler will complain if you are missing any of the methods). So, in most cases, you are not overriding any of the methods, merely implementing those methods. If you come up with a complicated framework, then it's possible to have any combination of `abstract` and `virtual` methods; this has nothing to do with the interface, just a feature of being able to subclass.

Answer (score 1):

To answer this directly, yes you can write a `Batchable` that overrides the `start` method just so long as your `Batchable` implementation `extends` another `abstract` or `virtual` implementation of `Batchable` that has a `virtual` (or `abstract`) `start`.

For example, if you start with something like this:

```
public virtual class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SomeObject> {
  public virtual System.Iterable start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

You can then do something like this:

```
public class MyOtherBatch extends MyBatch {
  public override System.Iterable start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

This may not be a common scenario, but the point is you can arrange to override a `Batchable.start` method implementation. Indeed, this is something we have done on occasion. By using a common base `Batchable` with multiple small variations we get the best of both worlds:

- We avoid code duplication while
- We ensure the admin can distinguish between the async jobs running on the org by simply looking at the class being executed.

The async jobs list can only show that sort of information, and does not show you any initial state data; if you have a single parameterised batch that is run for different `SObjects`, for example, the admin cannot tell which one is which.

To help, we actually create simple extended batchables on a per-object basis and name them accordingly. E.g. we might have a generic `Cleanup` batchable and have subclasses called `AccountCleanup` and `OpportunityCleanup` that work on `Account` and `Opportunity` respectively. Sometimes these subclasses may need to tweak the standard `Batchable` methods, so making the base class and it's methods `virtual` lets us do that.